# See CRS of all layers at once in QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

Is there a way to see the CRS of all layers in the layers panel at once in QGIS 3.2.0?
QGIS is running on Windows 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the CRS in TOC using this simple script:

```
for layer in QgsProject().instance().mapLayers().values():   
    crs = layer.crs().authid()
    layer.setName(layer.name() + ' (' + crs + ')')
```